# Is inner product preserved on change of basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, change-of-basis

Suppose we have a matrix $A$ over which an inner product is defined. Let us denote this inner product by $\langle, \rangle_A$.

Now let us suppose that this matrix $A$ is symmetric. Then there exists a matrix $Q$ such that $Q^TAQ$ is a diagonal matrix. For any two vectors $v$ and $w$, is $\langle v,w\rangle_A=\langle v,w\rangle_{Q^TAQ}$?

In other words, is inner product preserved when we change the basis of $R^n$?

Comment: The basis has to be orthogonal.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會- That's not necessarily true when diagonalizing a symmetric matrix though, right?

Comment: It's a well known result in linear algebra that symmetric matrices iff orthogonal eigenbasis.  I'm simply addressing the last prompt alone without previous context.

Comment: Is the inner product defined over $A$, or the inner product defined using $A$ over $\mathbb R^n$ using a canonical basis?